# What to do when you boss is hiring someone you know is unnecessary

Tags: new-hires

I'm part of a team of 4 people in charge of the platform (1 release engineer, 1 dba, 1 IT guy, and me partially responsible for IT and also software configuration mgr) for a software company.

We have experienced some sudden grow as we have hired one consulting company for providing us with a team of 5 sw developers working together with our people. In total we have reached a headcount of 50 (including administrative staff, general mgrs, project mgrs, analysts, developers and testers), even with this change, and given that we also hired another company providing us 5 another people in another outsourcing team for a different project, and as we also had to support them I don't see the need for it.

But my boss is insisting in hiring another release engineer, but we (as in 4 of us) also don't see the need for it. I was direct with him and confronted him about the idea but he still wants to have it his way.

These are scenarios that worry me: one is where the boss is hiding his intentions of get rid of one of us without telling directly. Other is when the workload is at its lowest after the outsourcing finishes or when inevitably the amount of headcount doesn't require a 5 people team for support. We also were planning to automate some stuff but when the other guy arrives it's likely to get to work on the new things, and then we get relegated.

How to handle above concerns?

Comment: Have you asked him why he is hiring, rather than just assume things?

Comment: You are going to have to expand, because we are still waiting for the question :)

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: Unnecessary is better than unqualified.  Be happy that you're getting the former and not the latter.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is do your job and stop trying to do the manager's job. You treat the new person well when he comes in and work with him with the same level of professionalism you work with everyone else (even if someone gets laid off or fired, it is certainly not this person's fault.)

Managers are often privy to infomration you don't have and that they are not free to give you. This would include the fact that someone is in the process of being fired or it could include new work coming up that they are not yet free to discuss for legal reasons. It could include the possibilities of organizational structure changes. It could just be that the budget became available.

I worked one place where all the development work got outsourced. It took well over a year of planning and the managers would have been fired if they had said anything. I have also worked some places where if the money became available to hire a new person, you did dso immediately before the money got transferred to some other task even if you were not quite ready for the new person.

I have worked places where the company was in contract negotiations that had to remain confidential (as their current provider might have been unaware that they were losing a customer) but which required the addition of new personnel. I have seen jobs created where none existed or were curenlty needed in order to hire someone perceived as really good or a relative of the CEO who just graduated from college (be especially nice to the person if this is the case!). None of those scenarios are ones the manager would be able to openly talk about to the team.

Answer (score 1):

In many companies, "headcount" (the number of people who report to you/who are in your organizational unit: dept, group, team) is a measure of a manager's clout.  I'm not willing to suggest this is the reason, but it is something to consider when a boss makes a seemingly unnecessary hire, or keeps a position filled that is unnecessary.

It sounds like you've already done what you can do.  I'm sure the boss is aware of the seasonality of your work (high periods and low periods).  You have already stated that you don't think the position is needed, but you really have no control otherwise.

If you truly feel the boss is looking to get rid of you or one of your teammates, and you value your current job, now is the time to shine and put out your best work.  Based on your information, though, that's not what I think it happening--**but you will know better than I**.

Answer (score 1):

Your boss is a manager. It is a manager's prerogative to make either stupid decisions or decisions that appear stupid.

I doubt that your boss shares everything with you including why he makes the hiring decisions he makes. He may be hiring that extra pair of hands because he figures the firm is in growth mode and the best time is to hire when the staff is no so busy with their own work that they can't train the Incoming. Or he made the offer because the Incoming is unusually good and the boss didn't want him to slip between his fingers and get away. Or he made the offer because the Incoming has a multiple skills set. Or somebody leaned on the boss to make the decision to hire.

This is the deal: you know the current situation - "we don't need more people" and you know your own perspective i.e. from the not-so-high branch that you are perched on within the management tree. But you don't know what factors went into the boss's decision, and I doubt that he is going to share that info with you any time soon because he certainly doesn't report to you. At some point, you'll look to him like you are second guessing him  without the facts in hand and you'll just be annoying him.

> Follow-up comment from @StephenKolassa "Another possibility: maybe the boss hired someone as a replacement for a current employee who will soon leave, either voluntarily or involuntarily. Managers do sometimes know more than employees."

Comment: +1. Another possibility: maybe the boss hired someone as a replacement for a current employee who will soon leave, either voluntarily or involuntarily. Managers *do* sometimes know more than employees.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am incorporating your comment into my answer. With full attribution to you, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> We also were planning to automate some stuff but when the other guy arrives it's likely to get to work on the new things, and then we get relegated.

Is it possible that your boss wants to accelerate this automation? Presumably, you haven't had enough bandwidth among the four of you to get the automation done thus far on top of your regular tasks, so maybe he thinks another engineer will be able to increase the pace of automation while maintaining your current operations.

At the end of the day, your boss thinks the position is a good idea even after you've expressed your opinion. You could try asking him to further explain his reasoning for wanting to expand, especially since it doesn't sound like you determined his reasoning while confronting him. Still, if it's his decision to make, there isn't much more you can do then make your reasoning clear.

Comment: This is an old, old, software development issue, going back at least to the 1970s, called the Mythical Man-Month. Adding another engineer to a project, especially one that is in its late stages, actually makes the job take *more* time, not less.

Comment: I'm familiar with the mythical man-month, but I'm proposing that the manager might be adding another person for what is effectively a new project. Basically, rather than having the current staff try to add automation on top of their current tasks, he has them continue as is and makes the automation a project for a different person. It certainly doesn't sound like automation is in the late stages for them. I don't think this is like the typical man month issue "we have 8 devs deep in the weed failing to finish this application, so let's add 8 more."